# C code allocating more memory than it should

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

For a course I'm doing a times-table style exercise in C. The code is fully functional, but the automatic tests are saying it's allocating 416 bytes, when it should only allocate 376. This is with the values a=2,b=9,c=11,d=17. I've run the code through valgrind with all possible extra details turned on, and it's not really helping.

I tried to write the header row generation to be a part of the main times table creation, but it just ended up using more memory than my current approach.

There should also be no issues with the destroyTimes function, since valgrind is not reporting any leaks.

Here is times.c

```
#include "times.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Times* createTimes(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d) {
  int i,j;
  int rows=d-c+2;
  int cols=b-a+2;
  
  Times* ret = malloc(sizeof(Times));
  uint** kert = malloc(sizeof(uint*)*rows);

  if (!ret) {
    return NULL;
  }

  ret->a=a;
  ret->b=b;
  ret->c=c;
  ret->d=d;

  kert[0] = malloc(sizeof(uint)*(cols+1)); 
  kert[0][0] = 1;

  for(j=1;j<cols;j++) {
    kert[0][j] = a;
    a++;
  }
  a = ret->a;

  for(i=1;i<rows;i++) {
    kert[i] = malloc(sizeof(uint)*(cols+1));
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++) {
      kert[i][j] = c*kert[0][j];
    }
    c++;
  };

  ret->times = kert;

  return ret;
}

void destroyTimes(Times* kt) {
  uint i;
  uint rows = kt->d - kt->c + 2;
  if (kt == NULL) {
      return;  
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      free(kt->times[i]);
  }
  free(kt->times);

  free(kt);
}
```

Then here is times.h

```
#ifndef TIMES_H
#define TIMES_H

typedef unsigned int uint;

struct Times {
  uint a,b,c,d;
  uint** times;
};

typedef struct Times Times;

Times* createTimes(uint,uint,uint,uint);

void destroyTimes(Times*);

#endif
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that `malloc` needs to allocate slightly more than you ask for as bookkeeping information, that the allocator uses to manage allocations, allocate more, and free. Since the amount of memory used is not terribly more than the amount you requested, this is likely the culprit.

Comment: How do I then pass said automatic tests? It's worked fine for previous assignments.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking there, but I noticed you have a `malloc()` in a for loop, and a good way to eliminate memory overhead is to replace many smaller allocations with a single larger one.

Comment: don't think you need to allocate `cols+1`, you're iterating up to `<cols` after each of those allocations, so that's an extra `sizeof(unit)` (probably 4 bytes) each time.

Comment: @yano got it, a previous version needed the +1 and I'd not spotted it. Removing that passes the tests

Comment: @user16217248 out of curiosity, how could I go about simply having one malloc call to allocate memory for the 2D array kert? I tried to google, but they seemed non-applicable to ISO C90.

Comment: @user16217248 true but a red herring here, maybe. The "automatic tests" may simply test how many bytes were requested in the call(s) to malloc (which was probably overridden in the test code) rather than how many bytes the malloc implementation allocated (to include control data).

Comment: @SirAchesis Instead of `arr[x][y]`, do `arr[x+y*cols]`

Comment: @SirAchesis Aside: which can be reviewed without looking elsewhere for checking the correct size: `kert[i] = malloc(sizeof(uint)*(cols+1));` or `kert[i] = malloc(sizeof kert[i][0] * (cols+1));`?

Comment: OT: `  uint rows = kt->d - kt->c + 2;
  if (kt == NULL) {
      return;  
  }` The check for NULL is too late.... A dereference has already been done...

Comment: There is a potential memory leak - `Times* ret = malloc(sizeof(Times)); uint** kert = malloc(sizeof(uint*)*rows); if (!ret) { return NULL; }` the memory was allocated for `ret` and if potentially `NULL` what happens to `kert` ? You need to put the `malloc` call for `kert` **AFTER** the check for `ret`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For a course I'm doing a times-table style exercise in C.

Okay, so you want to learn C. Cool...

But be aware that learning the C language is only getting you half the way. You also need to learn how to use a debugger. How to start a debug session. How to set break points. How to single step. How to inspect variable values. And so on...

Now seems to be a good time doing that.

Meanwhile C comes with a pretty powerful built-in debugger. It's called `printf` (*note 1*).

Adding small debug print outs when doing `malloc` will help you understand what is going on.

For instance:

```
  printf("rows=%d cols=%d\n", rows, cols);

  size_t total_alloc = 0;
  size_t current_alloc = 0;

  // Times* ret = malloc(sizeof(Times));
  current_alloc = sizeof(Times);
  total_alloc += current_alloc;
  printf("Allocating %zu bytes for Times (total = %zu)\n", current_alloc, total_alloc);
  Times* ret = malloc(current_alloc);

  // uint** kert = malloc(sizeof(uint*)*rows);
  current_alloc = sizeof(uint*)*rows;
  total_alloc += current_alloc;
  printf("Allocating %zu bytes for row-pointers (total = %zu)\n", current_alloc, total_alloc);
  uint** kert = malloc(current_alloc);

  // and likewise for all your malloc
```

After doing that I can run your program and get:

```
rows=8 cols=9
Allocating 24 bytes for Times (total = 24)
Allocating 64 bytes for row-pointers (total = 88)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 0 (total = 128)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 1 (total = 168)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 2 (total = 208)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 3 (total = 248)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 4 (total = 288)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 5 (total = 328)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 6 (total = 368)
Allocating 40 bytes for cols data in row 7 (total = 408)
```

(See *note 2*)

When looking at this output it's pretty simple to see that there something strange about the columns. How can 9 columns need 40 bytes? That's 4.44 bytes per column! Makes no sense. It's time to look at the column `malloc`:

```
  kert[i] = malloc(sizeof(uint)*(cols+1));
                                     ^^
                                oh, why did I add one here ???
                                I don't need 10 columns - only 9
```

After fixing the code (i.e. removing the `+ 1` both places) the program will now produce:

```
rows=8 cols=9
Allocating 24 bytes for Times (total = 24)
Allocating 64 bytes for row-pointers (total = 88)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 0 (total = 124)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 1 (total = 160)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 2 (total = 196)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 3 (total = 232)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 4 (total = 268)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 5 (total = 304)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 6 (total = 340)
Allocating 36 bytes for cols data in row 7 (total = 376)
```

Lesson: A few debug prints can be vey powerful for finding bugs. But going forward it's important to learn how to use a real debugger.

*note 1 : No, `printf` is not a debugger. Just joking... `printf` can't substitute a real debugger but doing small debug print outs can actually be pretty powerful for finding bugs in small programs.*

*note 2 : With your original code I got 408 bytes while you got 416. Not sure why it differs but maybe your compiler added 8 bytes of padding to the struct `Times`*

**A little extra**

```
  uint rows = kt->d - kt->c + 2;
  if (kt == NULL) {  <--- Too late... you all ready did the dereference
      return;  
  }
```

The check for NULL must be **before** `kt->d`